# Dealing with nan values in Dynamo DB - AWS

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a data frame with the following format:

```html
Product ID  Product type    Basic rate  Market cost 
ab12               Glass        20            220
ab34               Glass        nan           234
ab56              Plastic       55            245
ab87              Plastic       10            nan
```

I am trying to upload this data frame into AWS Dynamo Db with the following code( df being the pandas data frame and visData being the Database table):

```py
myl_list = df.T.to_dict().values()
print(myl_list)

   
   
#read the dynamo resource
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('VisData')
    
for Product ID in myl_list:
    table.put_item(Item=Produdt ID)
```

The original file had some missing values, those missing values were converted into "nan" when it was read as a data frame. The AWS Dynamo Db database does not accept "nan" as a cell entry rather I want it to be "empty string" and leave it blank while I upload it to the Database.

how can I do that? Please help

Comment: have you tried `df.replace(to_replace=np.nan, value="").T.to_dict().values()` which will replace all `NaN` beforehand

Comment: @gold_cy- Would you like to add that as an answer? I will accept it as a solution to this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to replace `NaN` values with empty strings you can accomplish this beforehand in the dataframe.

```
df.replace(to_replace=np.nan, value="").T.to_dict().values()
```